# Parameter 0 of constructor in ' ' required a bean of type ' ' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am creating a `spring boot application`, wherein any client can submit the request, these request can be `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE`.

But while creating this application, I am getting the following errors:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.idr.springboot.service.PersonService required a bean of type 'com.idr.springboot.dao.PersonDao' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - User-defined bean


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'com.idr.springboot.dao.PersonDao' in your configuration.
```

The structure of my application is:

[image]

**PersonDao.java**

```
package com.idr.springboot.dao;

import com.idr.springboot.model.Person;
import java.util.UUID;


public interface PersonDao {

    int insertPerson(UUID id, Person person);

    default int insertPerson(Person person) {
        UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
        return insertPerson(id, person);
    }


}
```

**PersonService.java**

```
package com.idr.springboot.service;

import com.idr.springboot.dao.PersonDao;
import com.idr.springboot.model.Person;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class PersonService {


    private final PersonDao personDao;

    @Autowired
    public PersonService(@Qualifier("fake demo") PersonDao personDao) {
        this.personDao = personDao;
    }


    public int addPerson(Person person) {
        return personDao.insertPerson(person);
    }
}
```

I know that many questions with the following error, are already been asked, but still I am not able to solve this.

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.idr.springboot.service.PersonService required a bean of type 'com.idr.springboot.dao.PersonDao' that could not be found.
```

I have tried to annotate `PersonDao.java` with `@Service`, `@Repository`, `@Component`, but still I am getting the same error.

I have even tried solutions from these SO answers :

(1) [Parameter 0 of constructor in required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52841620/parameter-0-of-constructor-in-required-a-bean-of-type-java-lang-string-that-co)

(2) [Spring - Error Parameter 0 of constructor in Service required a bean of type Configuration that could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52180328/spring-error-parameter-0-of-constructor-in-service-required-a-bean-of-type-con)

(3) [Parameter 0 of constructor in ..... Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50412208/parameter-0-of-constructor-in-spring-boot)

But still I am not able to resolve my issue.

Comment: What is your intention of the qualifier `@Qualifier("fake demo") PersonDao personDao` ?

Comment: `PersonDao` is not a `JpaRepository` nor a spring bean, you have to define it to be both

Comment: Okay @Lino, I got it, and my application started running successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding the qualifier `@Qualifier("fake demo")` to `public PersonService(@Qualifier("fake demo") PersonDao personDao)` a bean with that qualifier is searched to be injected in `PersonService` which does not exist. You can declare this qualifier as well on `PersonDao` or remove it. I would recommend removing it. In addition you should annotate `PersonDao` with `@Repository` and extend interface `org.springframework.data.repository.Repository`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the model, controller, and repository folders are at the same level as the main SpringbootApplication.java file